# Integrating Audit Logs In Rails Application With Mongodb

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, audit-logging

In my rails application, I want to store every activity that is performed on the model. I am using Postgresql DB but I want to store my logs in MongoDB so that my current infrastructure should not get impacted. I went through mongoid gem but it does not offer implementation along with Postgresql db.